# How to add a for attribe to a div like label's for?

Tags: javascript, html, label, for-loop

So what I want is a `div` what points to an `input` or a `div with contentEditable=true`.

So if a click on the div then jumps inside the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `<label>`.

If you really want to use a `<div>`, you'll need to use Javascript, like this:

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('ID of input element').focus()">...</div>
```

Comment: I really want to use a `<div>` :P, Javascript is fine.